# JDBC exception handling in Spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I am implementing a REST api webservice which is fetching data from a MySql database. It is written [here](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-exception-handling.html) that we dont need to handle database exception explicitly. I have catch blocks in the **Service** layer. I have the following questions.

1- How do i send the appropriate error message to the respective model view from the catch block?

2- Is Service the right layer to catch the exception?

I have the following code

**Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result) 
    {
       ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

       validator.validate(user, result);
       if(result.hasErrors()) {
           mv.setViewName("addUser");
       }
       else {
           service.saveUser(user);
           mv.setViewName("redirect:/users/listAllUsers");
       }
       return mv;
    }
```

**Service**

```
public void saveUser(User user) {
    try {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    } catch(DuplicateKeyException e) {
        //Here i want to send "User already exist"
    } catch(DataAccessException e) {
        //Here i want to send "Databae unreachable"
    }
}
```

**UserDAO**

```
public void saveUser(User user) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO User (fname, lname, address, phone)"
                    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, user.getFname(), user.getLname(),
                    user.getAddress(), user.getPhone()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you meant to display the error message in JSP page by `send the appropriate error message to the respective model view`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dbreaux 's answer is correct.You should customize an exception.

```
public class UserException extends RuntimeException {
      // You can add some custom variables
      // such as error codes, error types, etc.
}
```

Then,you should define a ControllerAdvice to handle this Exception:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class UserControllerAdvice{

    @ExceptionHandler(value = UserException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleUserException(UserException ex){

        // Generate corresponding results(ModelAndView) based on exception.
        // example: Put the error message to model. 
        return new ModelAndView("prompt_page",ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Last,you can throws `UserException` in your Service.

```
public void saveUser(User user) {
    try {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    } catch(DuplicateKeyException e) {
        throw new UserException("User already exist");
    } catch(DataAccessException e) {
        throw new UserException("Databae unreachable");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to isolate the web-specific behaviors from the service layer, and from the data layer, and I think the best way to do that is to throw a new, checked, domain-specific `Exception` that matches the meaning of each case you want to handle differently in the Controller.

For example, `DuplicateUserException`, `SystemUnavailableException`. Then the Controller catches those and adds the correct case to the Model.